# How can I get the XUL as a string from a Mozilla add-on at run-time using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to get a window's XUL text as a String in Javascript. I need it to be done at runtime because the window adds/removes UI elements dynamically.

I have tried the following:

```js
document.toXML()

document.xml

document.documentElement.toXML()
```

Among other things. Nothing works! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer):

```js
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a function or field to get xul text, but you can work around by reading the content from xul url

```
function getContentFromURL(url) {
  var Cc = Components.classes;
  var Ci = Components.interfaces;
  var ioService = Cc['@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
  var scriptableStream = Cc['@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1'].getService(Ci.nsIScriptableInputStream);

  var channel = ioService.newChannel(url, null, null);
  var input = channel.open();
  scriptableStream.init(input);
  return scriptableStream.read(input.available());
}
```

so you can call getContentFromURL(document.location) to get the XUL content

Comment: I am citing the question: "I need it to be done at runtime because the window adds/removes UI elements dynamically."